Undo change to field with VBA
I have a database used for lookup and only occasionally edited. To avoid unintended changes, I'm working on popping a prompt to confirm edits.
The database contains a single table with around 7k records and no forms.
What I have:

The Before Change Event of the table takes the SetLocalVar action, with the expression set to: =ConfirmEdit()
ConfirmEdit() is a VBA Function inside a Non-Class Module:

Option Compare Database

Public Function ConfirmEdit()

  If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to make this change?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Confirm Edit") = vbNo Then
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdUndo
  End If

End Function

Despite achieving the intended behavior, it show a warning when user cancels the edit.
First it shows this:

Followed by this after clicking No:

As far as I know, I can't use Me keyword as the code is not inside a class module to do something like Me.Undo.
Is there any solution not to raise that error or to hide it?

I don't think that data macros are suited for this task. You probably need a form. You can try DoCmd.SetWarnings False and/or On Error Resume Next in the function, don't know if it might help.

Thx for the response @Andre, I tried both and none worked.
Maybe I don't know the right way to use those in this context.

As far as I know you can only cancel an edit by using RaiseError in the macro. First create the following Before Change event macro:

Then you can create your function:
Public Function ConfirmEdit()

  ConfirmEdit = False
  If MsgBox("Are you sure you want to make this change?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Confirm Edit") = vbYes Then
    ConfirmEdit = True
  End If

End Function

In this example I have set the default button to No but you can choose whichever button you want. What happens now when you go to change a record, you will get the following prompt as per your original example:

And when you click No, you get a friendlier message as follows:

Note that you can change the text in that message.
I know it does not solve your issue with the second message however this is a cleaner approach to cancelling an edit. Unfortunately you will also need to hit the Escape key to undo your change.
And one final note, you should also do something similar for the Before Delete event.

Thx for the response @BobS, your approach is indeed neat.
I'm curious if it's possible to call another function when user chooses No to send an ESC keystroke (not sure if it's possible or works at all).
